# Good log colorizing script?

Tags: script, colors, logging

I'm looking for a script which I can pipe a log into, specifically the `tail -f` of a log, and it will colorize it. Log would be in syslog format but if there's a program that handles multiple formats (apache, exim, etc) that would be a plus. I used to have one of these back 9 years ago, a nifty little perl script, and I can't find it anymore!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [colorize.pl](http://freshmeat.net/projects/colorize_perl) -- an old favorite of mine for exactly this use.

Comment: Awesome, I think that was it! I don't know why I couldn't find this after 1+ hour of googling. Do you know a good config for syslog?

Comment: afraid I can't offer much help for a nice syslog config. I've only used it to tail apache logs for specific events. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I like multitail. You can see it on work on: http://satukubik.com/2010/01/07/multitail-colorize-your-log-files/